# Python: Module: same class name

Tags: python, module

I have a module defined with a class and a few functions. I am trying to import this module in my main script that also has a class defined with the same name. The main functions constructs a json with a 'Header' and a 'Body' and calls a function that returns it's 'Header' and a 'Body' as a json.

Main:

```
import myModule

class Header:
    def __init__(self, ID: str, DateTime: str, DSTFlag: str, IPAddr: str):
        self.ID = ID
        self.DateTime=DateTime
        self.DSTFlag=DSTFlag            
        self.IPAddr=IPAddr
```

myModule.py:

```
class Header:
    def __init__(self, Id=None, DateTime=None, DSTFlag=None):
        self.Id = Id            
        self.DateTime = DateTime
        self.DSTFlag = DSTFlag
```

Can I still import myModule into my main script without class name clash? Is each one defined in it's own namespace?

According to https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

"Each module has its own private namespace, which is used as the global namespace by all functions defined in the module. Thus, the author of a module can use global variables in the module without worrying about accidental clashes with a user’s global variables."

I'm not clear on this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes. You use `myModule.Header` to refer to the class from the module.

Comment: @Barmar: Thank you. If you could post your response, I'll accept it as a solution.